# Why does Selenium "flicker" between finding and not finding a particular HTML element?

Tags: selenium

I'm using Specflow/Selenium to automate test of a web application I'm working on in the ASP.Net environment. Most of the 'button clicks' lead to complete page loads. I execute the following lines of code to execute when clicking such a button, but it's a flickering piece of code - sometimes it finds the element and other times it fails. Why is that?

```
public class CreateQuestionPOM : BasePOM
{
    //Flickering find!
    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//label[text()[contains(.,'True/False')]]")] 
    private IWebElement trueFalseOption;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[@ct='Button' and @title='Next']")]
    private IWebElement nextButton; 

    public CreateQuestionPOM(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver) { }

    public void CreateTrueFalseQuestion()
    {            
        trueFalseOption.Click();
        nextButton.Click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(GetDriver(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)GetDriver()).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
    }

}
```

The above method signature is similar to all button clicks that happen on the page. The above piece of code is called after a previous button is clicked. The method is very similar to the above - wait for `document.readystate` to be `complete`. But why does this flicker so often and what is the recommended solution?

Comment: Maybe the page isn't fully loaded sometimes when the page is scraped?

Comment: I wouldn't think that to be the case given the `wait.Until` statement.

Comment: The clicks are happening before the wait.

Comment: Err...yes. The page load happens "after" the click. So click happens before wait. Not sure I understand...

Comment: The only elements that you are finding in this code snippet are before the wait. So... if the elements aren't being found, the wait isn't going to help.

Comment: Here's the flow: click and wait for new page. Each method calls a 'wait' after the click so that the next method can find the element on the new page fetched. The above method is called after another similar method is run. It's as if the wait returns on the current page itself instead of actually waiting before trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wait in your code, there is a `wait.until()`. When that code is executed, it is executed immediately and the `until` condition is checked. If the `until` condition is true, execution continues. Only if the `until` condition is false will there be a wait. If the code executes fast enough, the browser may not be transitioning to the next page before the `until` condition is checked. The `until` condition will pass because the current page (the page you clicked the element on) is already loaded. One thing you can try is to pick an element off the clicked page and wait for it to be stale. An element is stale when it is no longer in the DOM. When the next page is loaded, the elements on the previous page are stale. Try the code below and see if it helps.

```
public void CreateTrueFalseQuestion()
{            
    trueFalseOption.Click();
    nextButton.Click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(GetDriver(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    // when nextButton is stale you know the browser is transitioning...
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(nextButton));
    // ... then you wait for the new page to load
    wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)GetDriver()).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
}
```